# Application onTime not working after updating excel

Tags: excel, vba

i recently updated excel 2010 to excel 2016 , and for some unknown reason , Application on Time is not working now.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    WS_Count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For o = 1 To WS_Count
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(o).Unprotect password:="leicaoee"
    Next o
    Application.Visible = True
    interfaceform.Show
    'monitorform1.Show

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:30:00"), "Save1" '1º Turno 1º Intervalo Inicio
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:00:00"), "Save2" '1º Turno 1º Intervalo Fim
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:00:10"), "Save21" ' 1º Turno 2º Intervalo Inicio
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:30:00"), "Save3" '1º Turno 2º Intervalo Fim


    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:00:00"), "Save4" '2º Turno 1º Intervalo Inicio
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:30:00"), "Save5" '2º Turno 1º Intervalo Fim
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:30:10"), "Save51" '2º 2º Turno 2º Intervalo Inicio
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:00:00"), "Save6" '2º Turno 2º Intervalo Fim


    Application.OnTime TimeValue("02:00:00"), "Save7" '3º Turno 1º Intervalo INICIO
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("02:30:00"), "Save8" '3º Turno 1º Intervalo Fim
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("02:30:00"), "Save81" '3º3º Turno 2º Intervalo Inicio
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("03:00:00"), "Save9" '3º Turno 2º Intervalo Fim

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:15:00"), "Save10" 'Fim 1º Turno
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("22:15:00"), "Save11" 'Fim 2º Turno
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("06:15:00"), "Save12" 'Fim 3º Turno
End Sub
```

Before updating excel this worked perfect , but after update seem's that's not working anymore , i don't believe that the problem is while opening the workbook but instead with probably some excel options.

I have already changed option to run macros , etc...

Comment: Is the workbook_open code definitely being called, can you run it from the VB editor, see if there are any issues?

Comment: Yes , it's running properly , as i also have a userform openning . The only thing not running is the OnTime , i'ven tried to force it to a time where i could test it.

Comment: 'that's not working anymore' doesn't give us a lot to work with. Is there an error thrown? If so, what is it? It doesn't fire the event?

Comment: The form is opened modally before the code, so the code wont run until the form is closed I believe.

Comment: But it has always run , just when i update excel it stoped running. The event is not being fired

Answer (score 1):

I have excel 2016 and ontime works right.

Try doing a new procedure and call it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:50:00"), "Macro1" 
end sub

Sub Macro1()

' Macro1 Macro

MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question but more of a suggestion to diagnose the problem. Please use comments to make suggestions

Comment: Right Zac :) , for the next time.